# WeakTypeTag not working in implicit macro with no value argument

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

I'm using an implicit macro to generate a typeclass.

```
trait ColumnType[+A]

object ColumnType {
  implicit def materializeColumnType[A <: Product]: ColumnType[A] = macro MappedColumnTypeMacro.materializeColumnType[A]
}

case class MappedColumnTypeMacro(c: Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def materializeColumnType[A: c.WeakTypeTag]: c.Tree = {
    val typeOfA = c.weakTypeOf[A]
    val companion = typeOfA.typeSymbol.companion
    val applyMethod = findMethod(companion.typeSignature, "apply", typeOfA)
    val unapplyMethod = findMethod(companion.typeSignature, "unapply", typeOfA)
    val typeOfB = applyMethod.paramLists.head.head.asTerm.typeSignature
    q"MappedColumnType[$typeOfA, $typeOfB]($companion.$applyMethod, $companion.$unapplyMethod(_).get)"
  }

  def findMethod(companionType: Type, name: String, typeOfA: Type) = {
    companionType.member(TermName(name)) match {
      case method: MethodSymbol if method.paramLists.flatten.length == 1 => method
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"No matching $name method found on $typeOfA")
    }
  }
}

def column[A](name: String)(implicit columnType: ColumnType[A]) =
  TableColumn[A](tableAlias, name)(columnType)

case class WrappedInt(int: Int)

// This fails
val myColumn = column[WrappedInt]("mycolumn")
```

The reason it fails is because `typeOfA` is not being resolved to be `WrappedInt`. When using whitebox context this is resolved as `A` and when using blackbox context this is resolved as `Nothing`

Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the variance annotation - scalac considers `ColumnType[Nothing]` to be the most specific implicit candidate here, so it's going to infer `A` in `materializeColumnType` to `Nothing` regardless of what `A` is provided in the invocation of `column`.

In our macro workshop at flatMap 2014, we explain how to work around the issue: https://github.com/scalamacros/macrology201/commit/78779cc7f565dde003fe0da9e5357821b009917b.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. It was still inferring `Nothing`. I decided to think more deeply about the variance annotation and was able to remove it and replace the subclasses with marker traits. This fixed the macro and actually made some other code cleaner. Thanks for the pointer